# using form and php to store images in database

Tags: php

I have a site that I need to upload several images and have them story in the database. I found some examples that I think will work, but there has to be an easier way to do this.

Here is part of the form code.

```
<tr height="30">
<td>Upload Main Image :</td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2500000"> <input type="file" name="image">
</td>
</tr>

<tr height="30">
<td>Upload Image 2 :</td>
<td></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2500000"> <input type="file" name="image2">
</td>
</tr>
```

And this is how I seen how to upload the images.

```
$FName = "NULL";
$FName2 = "NULL";
if ($_FILES['image']['name'])
{
$FName = md5($_FILES['image']['name'] . time()) . "." . end(explode('.', $_FILES['image']['name']));
$NewFile = "../UImages/" . $FName;
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $NewFile))
    {
    die("Failed to move file " .$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']." to " . $FName);  
    }
}

if ($_FILES['image2']['name'])
{
$FName2 = md5($_FILES['image2']['name'] . time()) . "." . end(explode('.', $_FILES['image2']['name']));
$NewFile = "../UImages/" . $FName2;
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'], $NewFile))
    {
    die("Failed to move file " .$_FILES['image2']['tmp_name']." to " . $FName2);    
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Does this code not work? In which case, what's the problem with it?

Comment: This is probably better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I haven't tested it, I was wondering if there was an easier way or if this is the best way to do this.